# Make a bootable disk

Tags: windows, iso-image, bootable-media

There is an iso file for Windows installations that includes x86 and x64 editions and its size is 5.5GB.

How to make a bootable DVD-Disk from that iso whose size is (more than 4.7GB) 5.5 GB?

Regards

GN Jha

Answer (score 1):

There's two options - you can get and burn a *[dual layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-R_DL)* DVD R or RW - These hold up to 9 gb so space would hardly be an issue.

I'd personally prefer to get a USB drive of appropriate size  and use a tool like [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) (just point it at the ISO and destination) and just create a installer disk off of that

Comment: Thank you for referring me for Rufus. I already created bootable USB Flash with Rufus but I am concerned for making bootable DVD Disk.